# EdgeWebDriver Forbidden

Tags: edgedriver

For those who had problems with the ChromDriver with Selenium from an error and only opened the browser but the page driver.get(); it didn't work. This is the solution for Edge browser:

```
"package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

public class EdgeDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
//Set Path to Driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "/Users/sergeitiulenev/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64-2/msedgedriver-2");

//Set ChromeDriver Path


EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
         options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

         WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);"

Solved, just in case if anybody want to get answer.
```